# Printing numbers divisible by 2 but not 3?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
for (int i=n1; i < n2; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This code prints out all the numbers between n1 and n2 (which are generated randomly) that are both divisible by 2 and 3, but i only want to print out the numbers that are divisible by 2. How do i do this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  Well...30...

Comment: Do you know the `&&` and `!` operators?

Comment: 3 or 9 won't get printed. It prints only numbers divisible by 2!

Comment: try using && and ! operators as @Mephy mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're literally halfway there.

You need a second condition in which you mandate that the number is *not* divisible by 3.  It would look something like this:

```
!(i % 3 == 0)
```

Now, you need a boolean operator to only return true if both conditions are true.  That, I'll leave as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

(Others already gave the correct answer, but I will try to explain it a bit more naturally)

For computers, you need to write a sentence in a manner they can understand. You need to convert logical sentences like "divise by 2 but not by 3" to a bit more basic version, using only the words "not", "and" and "or". In your specific case, you want to say `the numbers that are divisible by 2 AND NOT divisible by 3`

As you already noticed, `N%X!=0` is a (ugly) way to write `N is divisible by X`. In Java, we use `!` to say `not` and `&&` to say `and`.

This way, `(N is divisible by 2) AND NOT (N is divisible by 3)` can be written `(N % 2 == 0) && !(N % 3 == 0)`. But we also have the `X not equal Y` operator (`X!=Y`), which is equivalent to `NOT (X equal Y)` but easier to understand, resulting in this code:

```
if ((i % 2 == 0) && (i % 3 != 0)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient solution is to print the even numbers (every second) which are not multiples of 3, (every third number)

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i += 6) {
     System.out.println(i);
     if (i + 2 < n)
         System.out.println(i + 2);
}
```

The modulus operation is expensive and this will print two numbers with each loop instead of two numbers every six loops.

Comment: I rather like this solution.  But what happens if n is odd? E.G. let `n = 3`.  The loop won't fire because the condition does not hold.

Comment: @Makoto Good point, it would have failed to print out the last number some of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I am use bit operator to for best performance (if `(i & 1) == 0`, **i** is **even number**). Because even number in binary always have the end is 0 digit.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n1 = 0;
        int n2 = 100;
        for (int i = n1; i < n2; i++) {
            if (((i & 1) == 0)) {
                if (i % 3 != 0) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//    Result:
//        2 4 8 10 14 16 20 22 26 28 32 34 38 40 44 46 50 52 56 58 62 64 68 70 74 76 80 82 86 88 92 94 98
```

There are better way, for example 3534 % 3 == 0, we have: sum of all digits (3 + 5 + 3 + 4) = 15, and 15 % 3 == 0... Let's code follow this.
When n is big, for example n2 = 99999999999999 , use sum of all digits is (9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9) % 3 == 0, and bit operator is very sense :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the logical and comparison operator `&&`

```
for (int i=n1; i < n2; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i % 3 != 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Your `if` conditional now asks if "i is divisible by 2 AND is not divisible by 3"